# heroku deployment Assertion failed

Tags: mongodb, heroku

Assertion failed: You must provide either mongoUrl|clientPromise|client in options
/app/node_modules/connect-mongo/build/main/lib/MongoStore.js:119throw new Error('Cannot init client. Please provide correct options');
Error: Cannot init client. Please provide correct options

I have been trying all day to deploy my blog website but can't get it to work.
here is code https://github.com/joshua-sigston/console.Blog

tried copy pasting, other deployment sites.

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. There's very little anyone can do without a [mre].